# How to clear default text from label in visual studio without making the label disappear visually

Tags: c#, label, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to remove the default text from a label in Visual Studio so in the design view I tried to delete the default text from the text property. But when I do so I cannot see the outlines of the label as a result, so I cant keep track on my labels or even access them anymore after deleting the default text.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and it's a windows form application template using Visual C#. Basically what I'm trying to do is to use labels for showing output on the form, and I don't want the labels to show anything until a button is clicked.

Thankful for any help on this!

Comment: Set their MinimumSize property or set AutoSize to False or select them from the combobox at the top of the Properties window or use the View > Document Outline tool window or assign their Text property in the form constructor.  Pick one.

Comment: if you remove all the text it will be disappear.  set the space then u can see the label outlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two options

1. You can set the values of the labels to a blank string in code on form startup i.e. lblName.Text = ""
2. You can remove the default values and give your labels a fixed width to see the outlines in the designers. The reason you do not see the outlines is that the label adjusts its width to the content within.